# jquery with WordPress loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, bpopup

I'm using [jquery.bpopup](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/) in a WordPress loop. As you can see, there is a a trigger id and a pop up id. How do Iimplement the jquery the correct way? Right now only the first post in the loop will work. Any help is greatly appreciated.

**the loop**

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

<a href="#" id="trigger_pop_up_<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>

<div id="pop_up_<?php the_ID(); ?> "> 
  <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?> ?>
  <p>some random content</p>
</div>

<?php endwhile;?>
```

**jquery**

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $('#trigger_pop_up_<?php the_ID(); ?>').bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#pop_up_<?php the_ID(); ?>').bPopup();

    });

  });
</script>
```

Comment: Where are you including the HTML and jQuery? `index.php`, `header.php`, or `footer.php`? Somewhere else? I have a few ideas of what could be causing your problem, but I need to know specifically where both of those bits of code are going before I can give you a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

PHP code doesn't get executed inside of javascript files so `<?php the_ID(); ?>` does nothing and will probably cause js errors which would prevent your code from even running.

What you have to do is parse the id field manually.

```
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

        // Binding a click event
        // From jQuery v.1.7.0 use .on() instead of .bind()
        $("a#[id*='trigger_pop_up_']").bind('click', function(e) {

            // Prevents the default action to be triggered. 
            e.preventDefault();

            var id_number = parseInt(this.attr('id').replace('trigger_pop_up_',''), 10);

            // Triggering bPopup when click event is fired
            $('#pop_up_' + id_number).bPopup();

    });

  });
</script>
```

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

First wrap a div around each item and assign a class instead of id to the anchor tag and popup content container:

```
<? while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="popup" id="popup_<? the_ID(); ?>">
        <a href="#" class="popup-button">
            <? the_title(); ?>
        </a>

        <div class="popup-content"> 
          <? the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
          <p>some random content</p>
        </div>
    </div>
<? endwhile; ?>
```

Secondly, in jQuery use these classes to bind the event using `on` instead of `bind`:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('.popup-button', 'click', function(e) {
            $(this).next('.popup-content').bPopup();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```